# Specific fuction is undefined for Java swig, maybe because it is the only function that uses strings

Tags: java, c++, string, undefined, swig

I managed to setup swig for Java.
It works fine except from the functions that use std::string.

My .hpp file has this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
    namespace AcornClient {

                int createConnection();     // Returns connection id

                int freeConnection( int );  // Connection

                int open( int,              // Connection
                          std::string,      // Site
                          std::string,      // Project
                          std::string,      // Dataset
                          std::string,      // Path
                          bool,             // Recurse
                          bool );           // Regex

                int close( int );           // Server context
        }
```

The interface is this:

```
%module AcornClientAPI
%include "std_string.i"
%include cpointer.i

typedef std::string String;

%{
  #include "../cpp/AcornClientAPI.hpp"
    #include <libxml/tree.h>
%}

%include typemaps.i

namespace AcornClient {


    int createConnection();     // Returns connection id

    int freeConnection( int );  // Connection

    int open( int,              // Connection
              std::string,      // Site
              std::string,      // Project
              std::string,      // Dataset
              std::string,      // Path
              bool,             // Recurse
              bool );           // Regex

    int close( int );     // Server context 
}
```

Thhe code compiles and ruuns correctly when  I run the functions createConnection and freeConnection.

When I try to use the fuction open in n Java like this:

```
int blah = AcornClientAPI.open(id, "blah1", "blah2", "blah3", "blah4", true, false);
```

I get this error

```
java: symbol lookup error: libBlah.so: undefined symbol: _ZN11AcornClient4openEiSsSsSsSsbb
```

It should be something wrong with the strings. It doesn't identify them.

Comment: but ... std::string isn't undefined at all... your question is very misleading

Comment: Oh I thought that was the problem. What is the problem then? because all the rest of the functions work.

Comment: With a little bit of name unmangling: undefined symbol: AcornClient::open  The issue isn't in your header (else your compiler would complain) but in that your open() function isn't found - hence why you get a linker error.

Comment: Yes you are right, let me change the title but still I don't get it the .java and ...JNI.java files that were created have the open function as well.

Comment: You'll need to include your (minimal) c++ file in the question.

Comment: At the moment my c++ functions are empty, the file includes the .hpp and the problem remains.

Comment: You've not posted it though.